# INSERT VALUES from another table and ADD NEW VALUES TOO into a table

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

I am trying to insert values into a table called **charterFlight**. What I'm trying to do is copy the aircraft_id, crew_id and customer_id from another table **AND** add/insert the remaining values as well.

```
INSERT INTO charterflight 
    (aircraft_id, crew_id, customer_id, flight_time, flight_date,destination)
SELECT 
     aircraft_id, crew_id, customer_id --(and the remaining values here)
FROM aircraft, crew, customer
```

Running the code above doesn't produce any error, however it doesn't insert any rows as well!!!!

Comment: Do ***all three*** of your source tables actualy have values in them?

Comment: Post your exact SQL please...

Comment: Does the select return any rows ? try running it without the insert as the general syntax looks ok to me.

Comment: Only if all three tables have values.  `{1,2,3} CROSS JOIN {a,b,c} CROSS JOIN {}` is still just `{}`

Comment: If some tables potentially don't have records, you'll need an outer join on those tables.

Comment: @Dems yes, they all have values.

Comment: @Ollie 
Error starting at line 1 in command:
INSERT INTO charterflight (aircraft_id, crew_id, customer_id, flight_time, flight_date,destination)
SELECT aircraft_id, crew_id, customer_id 
FROM aircraft, crew, customer 
Error at Command Line:1 Column:12
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00947: not enough values
00947. 00000 -  "not enough values"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: You said it *doesn't* produce an error, then give an error report?

Comment: @Dems my apologies, when i run it without the (flight_time, flight_date,destination) it doesnt produce any error, my mistake. Sorry!!!

Answer (score 1):

Based on this comment...

```
@Ollie Error starting at line 1 in command:
INSERT INTO charterflight (aircraft_id, crew_id, customer_id, flight_time, flight_date,destination)
SELECT aircraft_id, crew_id, customer_id
FROM aircraft, crew, customer
Error at Command Line:1 Column:12 Error report: SQL Error: ORA-00947: not enough values 00947. 00000 - "not enough values" *Cause: *Action:
```

You're trying to insert three values into a table that has 6 fields.

The number of fields in `INSERT INTO table (...)` must match the fields in the table.  And then the number fields in `SELECT ... FROM` must match those fields too.

Any mis-match causes the error you refer to.

**EDIT** : Reply to your comments

As best I can suggest, you insert every combination of Aircraft, Crew and Customer with the following...

```
INSERT INTO charterflight (aircraft_id, crew_id, customer_id, flight_time, flight_date, destination)
SELECT aircraft_id, crew_id, customer_id, NULL, NULL, NULL
FROM aircraft, crew, customer
```

Then you can replace the `NULL` values by hand separately another time.

If you don't want the `NULL` values for `flight_time, flight_date, destination`, then you could just copy the results of SELECT into EXCEL, and write a formular in Excel that makes your inster statement for you.

Beyond these two approaches I have to confess that I'm not actually sure what you want to happen.

Comment: I am aware of that and that's the problem i'm facing. I want to extract values for the first three fields from another table and add values manually for the remaining three fields which are (flight_time, flight_date,destination) How do i do that??? with a VALUES command???

Comment: @user1089592 - It depends, do you want the same values in every record?  If so just append `, 'a flight time', 'a flight date', 'a destination'`.  But if you want different values for each row, where do you intend to get those values from?  Are you going to join on another table to get them?  (Note, at the moment you;r doing a CROSS JOIN of all the tables, getting every possible combination regardless of values or relationship, is that actually what you want?)  Or you could just use `NULL, NULL, NULL` and then go back and UPDATE them manually or with an UPDATE query.

Comment: No, because every flight will have a different flight time, flight date, destination and is booked by different customer and flown by different crew(pilot)....I'm making up the values!!!

Comment: @user1089592 - Then you either need to JOIN on another table which contains those values.  Or specify defaults (such as the `, NULL, NULL, NULL` example I gave), and then UPDATE or edit them yourself.

Comment: how do i do that???? Am i not joining the table by the SELECT command and the FROM command?

Comment: until now i've been using INSERT INTO (table name) VALUES (then the values) However, now the (crew_id,customer_id and the aircraft_id) are foreign keys.....how do i insert values into foreign keys...that is basically my question.

Comment: @user1089592 - I've updated my answer with by best guess as to what you want.  But I have to confess that I'm not really sure what you're asking for.

Comment: it say "0 rows inserted" any suggestion as to why its returning with that message???

Comment: @user1089592 - Could you run this for me?  `SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM aircraft), (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM crew), (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customer)`

Comment: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 100

Comment: u know what i feel like i'm just wasting ur time man....when u cud be using this time on helping someone else....THank a lot for your help i really appreciate it man!!!!1

Comment: Sorry, forgot this is ORACLE.  Try adding `FROM DUAL` to the end of it.

Comment: i dont believe this, my crew count returned 0!!!!! when it was last night i added 10 crews...i remember this very well SMFH aircfat =4, customer=10....

Answer (score 0):

In case of php we can do it like this,

```
<?php
$var1='';   //some value
$var2='';   //some value
$var3='';   //some value

 $qry = "INSERT INTO charterflight 
    (aircraft_id, crew_id, customer_id, flight_time, flight_date,destination)
SELECT 
     aircraft_id, crew_id, customer_id ,$var1,$var2,$var3
FROM aircraft, crew, customer";
?>
```

We can pass the variables after the column names of the selected table for inserting.